# Return SQL Query results as a variable in python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, amazon-redshift

So, I'm working on a python scrip to fetch all rows from a specific column in redshfit. The idea is to then loop through each item from the column in a second SQL command to make alterations. For example, I'm thinking of pulling the table names from a specific schema, then executing an ALTER TABLE to change the owner of each table. Here's the code I've got:

```
def alter_table(schema,new_owner):
    select = "SELECT talbe_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE talbe_schema = %s"
    args = (schema,)
    cur.execute(select,args)
    for table_name in cur:
        print table_name
        alter = "ALTER TABLE %s.%s OWNER TO %s"
        args2 = (table_name,schema,new_owner)
        cur.execute(alter,args2)
        cur.conn.commit()
```

Now, this *almost* works. The issue I'm having is passing the "table_name" from the select statement to the alter statement. The select statement gives the following output in the print command:

```
('TABLE_NAME',)
```

Which then gets passed to the alter statement like:

```
 ALTER TABLE ('TABLE_NAME',).schema OWNER TO new_Owner
```

The alter statement then fails with:

```
 syntax error at or near "("
```

What I *think* needs to happen is the special characters from the select statement need to be removed so that TABLE_NAME is passed down without them. Apparently my Googling skills are missing something so any ideas will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`AsIs`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.AsIs)

```
args2 = (AsIs(schema), AsIs(table_name[0]), AsIs(new_owner))
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response!  I had to make a change to the for loop so that the command iterates over each table name, but it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `table_name[0]`, because `table_name` is a `tuple` and the string you want is at index 0.

So make it like

```
args2 = (table_name[0],schema,new_owner)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! This, unfortunately, results in a syntax error as it looks like it encapsulates single quotes to each variable. The command ends up looking like `ALTER TABLE 'table_name'.'schema' OWNER TO 'new_owner'`. Apparently redshift doesn't like that formatting...